# Generate oscillation (approx. f=50 HZ, Ampl=20 MikroMeter )

Tags: oscillators, microscopy

I want to adapt the height of a sample under a microscope. I have an x-y-positioner but no z-positioner. As a x-y-z-positioner is too expensive (about 16 k €) I want to build an own solution. First idea was using Piezo-Actuators, which are also not that cheap.

So I wonder if you have any ideas how I can adapt the height of the sample. The sample's size is 75cm*25cm and its weight about 7 g. The oscillation should have a frequency of about 50 HZ and an amplitude of about 20 MikroMeters (^-6). Furthermore the position of rest of the oscillation should be adaptable up to 1 mm. The accuracy of the z-position should be about 1 MikroMeter.

I was thinking about somehow use coils and magnetic fields to generate oscillations but couldnt quite figure out how to do so.

Any ideas are appreciated.